# Set NOT NULL columns in koalas to_table

Tags: pyspark, databricks, delta-lake, spark-koalas

when I create a Delta table I can set some columns to be NOT NULL

```
CREATE TABLE [db_name.]table_name
  [(col_name1 col_type1 [NOT NULL], ...)]
  USING DELTA
```

Is there any way to set non null columns with `koalas.to_table`?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do directly from `koalas.to_table`, but you can use `ALTER TABLE` statement to add the constraint after you wrote the data (full [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-constraints.html)):

```sql
ALTER TABLE <table_name> CHANGE COLUMN <col_name> SET NOT NULL;
```

(for example, via `spark.sql` command)